# Reference a setup.py file when Running Dataflow Job on Composer

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a Dataflow pipeline that has the following general file structure:

```
root_dir/
  setup.py
  pipeline_main.py
  requirements.txt
  dependencies_dir/
     __init__.py
     some_functions.py
```

My setup.py file is something along the lines of the following:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
   name=<name>,
   version='1.0.0',
   install_requires = [],
   packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
)
```

This works fine as a standalone code, but I am working to incorporate this into Composer. I know with Airflow we can use the 'plugins' folders for importing functions. But the purpose of this setup.py and requirements.txt is to install the required dependencies for the Dataflow workers. In the local file system, we would use something like '--setup-file=./setup.py' and 'requirements_file=./requirements.txt' for the Dataflow options parameters.

Is there a specific directory in Airflow that I can use for the setup.py (and corresponding packages) as well as the requirements.txt?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for Cloud Composer shows you how you can install packages into the environment [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/install-python-dependencies#gcloud_2).

There is no directory - to update a Cloud Composer environment you must interact with the environment directly. Either through the API, Terraform, GCloud or Web console.

You can install packages from a `requirements.txt` locally on your machine:

```
gcloud composer environments update ENVIRONMENT_NAME \
  --location LOCATION \
  --update-pypi-packages-from-file requirements.txt
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for your response. Apologies if maybe my explanation was not too clear. These dependency installations are not necessarily for the Airflow environment, as they are for the Dataflow pipeline that is a task within our DAG. If I develop this locally, I can easily reference the requirements.txt and setup.py in my folder structure. I am wondering how I can create this file structure (or something like it) in the airflow env. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone who runs into the problem in the future, there are three folders that Airflow can natively read: `dags/`, `data/`, and `plugins/`.

The way it worked for me was the include the `setup.py` and `requirements.txt` in the `data/` folder.. For some reason, Dataflow will not natively read an absoulte GCS directory, but you could use Airflow's artificial file system, in the data folder example being `/home/airflow/gcs/data`. This value may vary based on your Airflow configurations, but it will execute if you set the proper directory.